# How to use Orbbec Astra depth sensor with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, openni, orbbec

I am currently working with an [Orbbec Astra Mini](http://shop-orbbec3d-com.3dcartstores.com/Orbbec-Astra-Mini_p_40.html) depth sensor. I downloaded and installed the [Astra Driver and OpenNI2](https://orbbec3d.com/develop/) package. The depth sensor is shown in the device manager on my Windows 10 as soon as I attach it to the USB port. So far everything is fine.

My goal is to read `RGB images` and the `depth map` with OpenCV and show them with `imshow`.

The following code compiles fine in Visual Studio 2015, but I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp
```

... so I guess that OpenCV couldn't open the device and therefore my cv::Mat keeps being empty.

I somewhere read that I need to compile OpenCV with the OpenNI flag - is that true? If so, any useful links that might help me to make some progress? Any ideas what I might have missed?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<System.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR_OUTPUT_MODE, CV_CAP_OPENNI_VGA_30HZ);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_GENERATOR_REGISTRATION, 1);

    cv::Mat im, dm;     // rgb image, depth map

    while (true)
    {

        if (cap.grab()) {
            cap.retrieve(im, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE);
            cap.retrieve(dm, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP);
        } else {
            cout << "ERROR: Could not grab image data." << endl;
        }

        if (!im.data) {
            cout << "ERROR: RGB not retrieved." << endl;
        }

        if (!dm.data) {
            cout << "ERROR: Depth map not retrieved." << endl;
        }

        cv::imshow("Image", im);
        cv::imshow("Depth", dm);

        if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    cap.release();

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 19.02.18:**

Issue solved by compiling the OpenCV libraries with the OpenNI flag as described [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html). Thank you Dmitrii!

However, the depth image is still quite weak. Any ideas where/how to adjust the parameters? Although, when running the sample applications of the Orbbec Astra SDK, the depth image is quite solid (which are working with OpenGL). So I guess the problem is somewhere within OpenCV?

Here's a screenshot of the depth map (inverted to white, quite weak resonance):

[image]

Comment: So why won't you compile opencv with openni support? I can see `WITH_OPENNI` flag in `CMakeLists.txt`. OpenCV documentation has a pretty excessive [installation guide](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) for windows

Comment: Thank you! Will go through the tutorial and report back.

Comment: @ Dmitrii Z.: Thanks for your help! It's now working with OpenCV+OpenNI+AstraSDK+ORBSLAM2. Any ideas how to adjust depth camera properties in OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an [comprehensive guide](http://nicolas.baumgardt.ch/slam/ORBSLAM2_Install_Guide_Win10.pdf) how to to compile [ORB SLAM 2](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2) (which was my preliminary goal) with [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) including [OpenNI2](https://structure.io/openni) in order to use my [Orbbec Astra camera](https://orbbec3d.com/products/) as depth sensor. Hopefully someone else stumbling over this thread can use it.

Comment: Comprehensive guide link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> However, the depth image is still quite weak. Any ideas where/how to adjust the parameters? Although, when running the sample applications of the Orbbec Astra SDK, the depth image is quite solid (which are working with OpenGL). So I guess the problem is somewhere within OpenCV?

Try implementing a false color map to the depth image. The different depth pixels have closely varying values, and thus not easily discernible if seen directly.

```
 // Holds the colormap version of the image:
 Mat img_color;
 // Apply the colormap:
 applyColorMap(img_in, img_color, COLORMAP_JET);
 // Show the result:
 imshow("colorMap", img_color);
```

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html